# DateEdit set a date value on the client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

How to set date from one dateEdit to another.
I have two dateedit properties. When one dateEdit (date1) changes i need to set some value on another dateedit. I have created ondatechanged function which has some logics and then i need to set the value to date2 field. i have used js/jquery to set but the value does not bind properly after focusing or clicking the changed date2 Dateedit.

**In my View**

```
 @Html.Hidden("dateTemp")
<label>R2Date</label>                    
@Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(
settings =>
{    
settings.Name = "date1";
settings.Properties.NullText = "MM/dd/yyyy";
settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(27);
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DateChanged = "OnDateChanged";
}).Bind(Model.r2date).GetHtml()


<label>RDate</label>
@Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(
settings =>
{
settings.Name = "date2";
settings.Properties.NullText = "MM/dd/yyyy";
settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(27);
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DateChanged = "ReportOnDateChanged";
}).Bind(Model.date1).GetHtml()



 [JScript]
    function OnDateChanged(s, e) {
    var dateVal = s.GetText();
   //my logic here
    dateOnchange();
    }
    dateOnchange(){
    //my logic here just need to call reportondatechange()
     ReportOnDateChanged();
    }

    function ReportOnDateChanged(s,e ) 
    {
     dateVal1 = $("#dateTemp").val(); //dateval1 has some values here 
      s.SetDate(dateVal1);//not working how to set the value here
    }
```

Comment: You do not have an element with `id="dateTemp"`. I assume you mean `dateVal1 = $("#date1").val()

Comment: i have hidden field set on my view, jus updated my question

Comment: But it does not have a value so `dateVal1 = $("#dateTemp").val();` will return `null` and therefore `s.SetDate(dateVal1);` will set the value to `null`. Its unclear what your trying to do (which control do you want to set a value to and when?)

Comment: i have some value at dateval1 i just want to know how to call   ReportOnDateChanged() this function because the main function has s,e parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientControl_GetControlCollectiontopic

This should do it

```
 var editor = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("date2");
            if (editor) {
                editor.SetValue(dateVal1);
            }
            $("#date2").val(dateVal1);
```